# Identifying duplicates when copy/paste of multiple cells into excel column

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to find a solution where i can copy paste multiple values from one column into another column and have it leave out duplicates already existing.

I found this code but it only works if I copy paste one value at a time.

Is there a way to make it work so it will paste in unique copied values only, that does not exist in the column already?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Prevents duplicate entries in Column A
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Column = 1 And Target <> vbNullString Then                           'Column A
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(1), Target) > 1 Then
            MsgBox "Entry " & Target & " already exists!", _
                vbCritical, "Dixons Travel Oslo"
            Target = ""
            Target.Select
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps using a `For` loop to go through all of the cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you find this usefull:

Below code assumes you just copy in all the values, even if they exist allready.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End If

End Sub
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Change `Header:=xlNo` to `Header:=xlYes` if that applies to your situation.

Obviously, there are other ways. I just find this quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

Using a similar methodology to your existing one, you could do the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each tcell In Target.Cells
        With tcell
        If .Column = 1 And .Value <> vbNullString Then     'Column A
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(1), .Value) > 1 Then
                tcell.Value = ""
            End If
        End If
        End With
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

Here's another way - expanding and improving on JvdV's idea:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target.Parent
        If Not (Intersect(Target, .Columns(1)) Is Nothing) Then
            Range("A1", Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This allows for multiple cells to be pasted - regardless of how many *columns* are affected and de-dupes the **whole** of column A.

Comment: Good additions @CLR

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Notes:

- You could change sheet name
- Header option

Comment: You left in the `If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then` ??

Comment: yes, in my opinion is one way to avoid error if the user use more than one cell which cause to an error.

Comment: But the OP wants a solution that allows for several cells being pasted at once?

Comment: @CLR you are absolutely right, i have correct the correct. More over, vbNullString check i think is not useful in the situation.

Comment: I *think* the vbNullString check was in there to remove the need to disable events - as the change event can cause a change in itself.

Comment: in my opinion is better to disable application event to avoid continues loop.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. I'm just explaining why I think it's there.